# What's wrong with my mouse config file?

Tags: mouse

Based on various things I read after hours of confused research, I made this config file, made it executable, and set it to run 5 seconds after startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
#wait for the desktop to settle
sleep 5

# speed up mouse
xset m 198 180

# turn off mouse acceleration
xinput set-prop 10 259 -1


device=" USB OPTICAL MOUSE"
resolution_percent=300

xinput set-prop "$device" "Device Accel Profile" 4
xinput set-ptr-feedback "$device" 0 "$resolution_percent" 150
xinput set-prop "$device" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1

# mouse wheel speed
imwheel
```

However, the mouse pointer still isn't as fast as I'd like, and there's some acceleration.  I want a constant 1:1 mapping between my hand and the pointer, so no acceleration is desired.  What to change?